# FindByExample in JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, reflection, jpql

I have decided to write a general findByExample method in my abstract DAO.

my result is :

```
public List<T> findByExample(T example) throws DAOException {
    try {
        Object object = example;
        String query = "SELECT e from " + object.getClass().getName() + " e where 1 = 1";
        for (Field field : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            Object fieldValue;
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (field.get(object) instanceof List || (java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()))) {
                continue;
            } else {
                fieldValue = field.get(object);
                if (fieldValue != null) {
                    if((fieldValue instanceof String) && !((String)fieldValue).isEmpty())
                    {
                        query += " and e." + field.getName() + " LIKE :" + field.getName();
                    }
                    else
                        query += " and e." + field.getName() + " = :" + field.getName();
                }
            }
        }

        Query q = em.createQuery(query, object.getClass());

        for (Field field : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            Object fieldValue;
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (field.get(object) instanceof List || (java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()))) {
                continue;
            } else {
                fieldValue = field.get(object);
                if (fieldValue != null) {
                    if((fieldValue instanceof String) && !((String)fieldValue).isEmpty())
                    {
                        q.setParameter(field.getName(), "%" + field.get(object) + "%");
                    }
                    else
                        q.setParameter(field.getName(), field.get(object));
                }
            }
        }
        return q.getResultList();

    } catch (SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {

        throw new DAOException("", e);
    }
}
```

I have written it with these Assumptions :

1. My query will search bidirectional String like search for my
   String fields
2. All declared fields of my entity are valid for my
   query.

How do you think about this piece of code? any better experience?
Also please tell me if you see any bug or something like that.

Comment: Nice, I was writing something like that a year ago, but using Criteria API

Comment: Consider moving it to "Code Review".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final edition code to solve this problem is below, I hope it helps you too.

```
public List<T> findByExample(T example, Map<String, SortOrder> sortMap, int startIndex, int pageSize) throws DAOException {
    try {
        Object object = example;
        String query = "SELECT e from " + object.getClass().getName() + " e where 1 = 1";
        if(!(object instanceof BaseEntity))
        {
            throw new DAOException(null, null);
        }
        Field[] fields = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            Object fieldValue;
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (field.get(object) instanceof List || (java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) || field.getName().startsWith("_")) {
                continue;
            } else {
                fieldValue = field.get(object);
                if (fieldValue != null) {
                    if ((fieldValue instanceof String) && !((String) fieldValue).isEmpty()) {
                        query += " and e." + field.getName() + " LIKE :" + field.getName();
                    } else {
                        query += " and e." + field.getName() + " = :" + field.getName();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(sortMap != null && !sortMap.isEmpty())
        {
            for(Entry<String, SortOrder> entry : sortMap.entrySet())
            {
                query += " ORDER BY e." + entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue().name();
            }
        }
        Query q = em.createQuery(query, object.getClass());

        for (Field field : fields) {
            Object fieldValue;
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (field.get(object) instanceof List || (java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) || field.getName().startsWith("_")) {
                continue;
            } else {
                fieldValue = field.get(object);
                if (fieldValue != null) {
                    if ((fieldValue instanceof String) && !((String) fieldValue).isEmpty()) {
                        q.setParameter(field.getName(), "%" + field.get(object) + "%");
                    } else {
                        q.setParameter(field.getName(), field.get(object));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return q.setFirstResult(startIndex).setMaxResults(pageSize).getResultList();

    } catch (SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {

        throw new DAOException(null, e);
    }
}
```